# Joining Large Spark dataframes

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, join

I have two data frames

DatFrame1 :

```
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- items: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

DataFrame2

```
 |-- item: string (nullable = true)
 |-- vector: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
```

Joined DataFrame

```
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- combinedVector : array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
```

I am looking to join these two data frames effectively. The data sets are big enough (in 100s of GB is size to broadcast them).
the items in first data frame can have upto 1000 values and each Array[Double] in second DataFrame can be large in size (upto 5MB when compressed and saved as parquet).

Can someone help me how this can be done ?

Comment: would you clarify your question , you want to join them based on which condition ? even though what is the problem, since you are speaking about the size and  brodcast would you give more details about your spark cluster props ?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the operations you like to perform and the cluster size but I'd suggest optimizations such as increase/decrease partitions size / repartioning based on the cluster, just select columns needed rather than selecting the whole dataset etc

Answer (score 0):

If one of the DataFrames is quite small (as you mentioned 5MB with compression as parquet), you sure can join them with broadcasting the small DataFrame. By doing so, the small DataFrame is conveyed to every executor in your Spark cluster, hence, speeding up the performance to some extent.

```py
## Python example
result = df_1.join(broadcast(df_2), on="key", how="inner")
```

**With Spark version above 3.0.0 (including)**
*assume `df_2` is the small DataFrame*

1. You can do this because all of the join hints are supported.

```scala
// Scala example
df_1.createOrReplaceTempView('df_1')
df_2.createOrReplaceTempView('df_2')
val result = spark.sql("""
    SELECT /*+ BROADCAST(df_2) */ df_1.key, df_1.col2, df_2.col4
    FROM df_1 JOIN df_2 ON df_1.key = df_2.key
""")
```

2. enable the AQE feature
   *One of the functionalities provided by AQE is to optimize the physical execution plan of the query, such as `SortMergeJoin` into a `BroadcastHashJoin`.*

```
spark.sql.adaptive.enabled=true
```

```py
## Python example
df_1.createOrReplaceTempView('df_1')
df_2.createOrReplaceTempView('df_2')
result = spark.sql("""
    SELECT df_1.key, df_1.col2, df_2.col4
    FROM df_1 JOIN df_2 ON 
       df_1.key = df_2.key
""")
```

**Some references you might find useful**

1. Li, J. 2021. *On Improving Broadcast Joins in Apache Spark SQL*. [ONLINE] Available at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9aY7KkTLTw&feature=emb_title. [Accessed 29 January 2021].
2. docs.databricks.com. n.d. *Adaptive Query Execution Demo*. [ONLINE] Available at: https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/aqe-demo.html. [Accessed 29 January 2021].

Comment: Thanks for you response. I will look at the examples you mentioned and see anyone works for me. So each element (column name 'vector' ) in DataFrame2 can be upto 5MB. That dataframe itself can have 1M rows. The size will be in 100 os GBs. So broadcast join is not good in this case. I was just trying to see if this can be done witIh spark itself or need distributed caching like Alluxio.